# How can I animate a 3d object in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
p3.autoscale = True
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

u = np.r_[0:2*np.pi:100j]
v = np.r_[0:np.pi:100j]

scale = 15
x = scale * np.outer(np.cos(u),np.sin(v))
y = scale * np.outer(np.sin(u),np.sin(v))
z = scale * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)),np.cos(v))

Line3DCollection_1 = ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, rstride=50, cstride=50)
Line3DCollection_2 = ax.plot_wireframe(x + 50,y,z, rstride=50, cstride=50)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    return Line3DCollection_1,
def animate(i):
    print("frame :"  + str(i))
    x = 50 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    y = 50 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    path = plt.plot([x],[y],[0], 'bo')
    return path

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=360, interval=0.1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

This will produce 2 spheres and a path that I want one of the spheres to take, but I'm not sure how to include this in the animation, I can animate the path, but not the 'Line3DCollection_2' sphere.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a proper answer, but I'd recommend taking a look at [`mayavi2`](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html). It has a proper OpenGL backend and is way more powerful than `matplotlib`'s rudimentary 3D capabilities. There's an example of a 3D animation [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html)

Comment: Mine isn't also an answer to the question, but I'd recommend visual python (http://www.vpython.org/) for animating 3D objects.